# React native wrapper component re-renders on each page navigation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, components

I am developing an android app using react-native and i have a but of a struggle of figuring out why my component re-renders on each page navigation.

In my case i have created a wrapper component called Container.android.js

```
const Container = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetching some data from async storage
  },[])

  // Using my hook here
  const {code, error} = usePdaScan({ 
    onEvent: (code) => {
        // setting state via useState
    }, 
    onError: (error) => { 
        Alert.alert('Error', error); 
    }, 
    trigger: 'always'
  });

  return <View>
  {props.children}
  </View>
}
```

Then i declare routes with Stack.Screen where each stack uses a component wrapped with the Container component.

```
<Stack.Screen name="Overview" component={Overview} />
```

And my Overview compnent is this

```
const Overview = props => {
   return <Container>
        <Text>Overview page</Text>
   </Container>
}
```

My problem is that inside the Container component, there is a hook called usePdaScan. Each time i navigate to another page and the hook gets called, the Container component re-renders twice... I cant get a lead on this... Halp!

UPDATE: My homepage is a class component where it seems to work ok (render only once)

```
class Home extends Component {

state = {
    productBarcodes: null
}

componentDidMount(){
    // get data fetches data from async storage
    getData('@productBarcodes').then(res => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            productBarcodes: JSON.parse(res)
        })
    })
}

render() {
    const { productBarcodes } = this.state;
    return (
        <Container {...this.props}>
            <View style={{marginBottom: 20, flex:1}}>
             {productBarcodes.length} Products
            </View>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

}

The usePdaScan hook in the Container component gets called once on my Homepage but twice on every other page like Overview etc... Both Homepage and Overview are wrapped with my Container component

Comment: Does `onEvent` fires everytime? If yes, then setting a state causes the rerendering.

Comment: So this is a barcode scanner hook which listens to barcode scans ... But the problem is i also have a Home page component which is wrapped with the Container component but there it doesnt seem to re-render twice.

Comment: Well I mean, if you navigate to a page, then this is the first rerender, if you open the scanner and set a new state, then this is the second rerender, or am I missing something?

Comment: The barcode scanner hook gets called only once on the Home page... But twice on every other page. I.E. Open the app and on the homepage ... i scan a barcode it re-renders once ... But if i go to Overview and scan barcode ... the scanner hook gets called twice and re-renders the component twice

Comment: Please, share your code of your HomePage as well as the usePdaScan hook as well as the part where you are `setting state via useState` as you have called it.

Comment: i updated the code snippet above